# Mouse cursor moves but Clicks are not working

Tags: mouse, touchpad, freeze

I am using Xubuntu 22.04 LTS. When running apps like libre office, VirtualBox os etc... suddenly and very often it happens that mouse cursor moves fine but Clicks do not respond. I tried CTL+alt+F1 then CTL+alt+f7, it doesn't solve the problem, just switches between home and console. If I run sudo pkill lightdm from console, it logs me out, Clicks get restored, but then I cannot decrypt my veracrypt container anymore, until reboot completely. Having so much pain from this disaster. Any help will be life saver. Thanks in advance.